# Validate file upload conditionally

Tags: php, yii

I have a database table that rules my file uploads.
The table, describes the files that have to be uploaded in a form. So basically, it contains the fields to describe to a user the file or files that he will have to upload.
The important fields on the table are: the description of the file, a required field that tells me if the file is required before allowing form submit and a max field that limits the number of files of the same type to be uploaded.
I want to trigger a validation rule when the required column value is true.

```
class Plan extends CActiveRecord{
    public $Letter, $Copy, $Chamber, $License, $Certificate, $Plans;
    public function rules(){
        return array(
            array( 'id_user, id_type, id_rental, id_city, PropiedadT, date', 'required', 'on' => 'final' ),
            array( 'Letter, Copy, License, Certificate, Chamber, Plans', 'fileExist', 'file','types' => 'jpg,JPG,pdf,doc,docx', 'allowEmpty' => false, 'wrongType'=>'Invalid file', 'on' => 'final', 'message' => 'You must attach a file') );
    }

    public function fileExist($attribute, $params){
        if( !empty( $this->{$attribute} ) ){
            $record = file_exists( "/opt/lampp/htdocs" . Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/files/Plan/" . $this->{$attribute} );
            if( !$record ){
                $this->addError( $attribute, 'You must attach a file' . $this->{$attribute} );
            }
        }
        else{
            $this->addError( $attribute, 'You must attach a file' );
        }
    }
}
```

I was just wondering where can i put that rule and how.

[image]

Basically, i have a form that a user needs to complete for a permit 'X'. Each permit has a different type and based on this type, the user needs to attach different files. The files that the user needs to attach are stored in the documentation table. This table describes the file and marks it as required or not required.
Each permit can have a different number of files and even no files at all. The files can be required or not.
My question intends to have the possibility to create a validation rule for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly declare rule for file upload field in model class

```
public function rules()
{
        return array(
            array('image','required','on'=>'final'),
            array('image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png'),
        );
}
```

Now In your controller action, add the following line

```
$model=new Item;
if(isset($_POST['Item']))
{
    $model->attributes=$_POST['Item'];
    $model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
    if($model->save())
    {
        $model->image->saveAs('path/to/localFile');
        // redirect to success page
    }
}
```

Make sure you add enctype in the form
`'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')`,

For detailed information, please follow the link
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/

Comment: I appreciate the answer, can you please explain me the line: `array('image','required'=>'on'=>'final'),` i find confuse the `'required'=>'on'=>'final'`. Is that `required`, the name of the field or should i put the required in the tag. I don't really understand how this value will be taken from the database field.

Comment: Here, 'image' is the name of the field which you want to be required.
You have to put this in your model class.

Comment: Maybe i was not clear. My problem is that i want the form to be dynamically created. There is a field called `required` in a table for the images. If that field is set to `true`, the field must be required, otherwise it will not be. I want to create a rule that takes this field into consideration.

Comment: Would you please share the table structure i will check and update you

Comment: Ok, i updated the question with a basic diagram of the database. Can You please check it out and let me know if this contains sufficient information to solve the problem? Thanks